# Input values from MagicSuggest are not being sent to database?

Tags: python, flask, magicsuggest

I have a form using MagicSuggest. When I type the values into the text input, each value is split and sent to a hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="author[]" value="{ value1here }">`). When I save the form, all I find in the db is an empty space. I'm not sure how to pass the hidden values to the db as well. I don't understand how to get my `form.author.data` to not be an empty space. Am I supposed to do something special to the inputs client-side?

Python (this leads to a `InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>`):

```
class BookView(BaseViewMixin, MethodView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.form = BookForm()
    def post(self, id):
        form = self.form
        if self.form.validate_on_submit():
            authorString = form.author.data
            authors = authorString.split(',')
            authorlist = []
            for au in authors:
                if au.strip() not in [a.name for a in authorlist]:
                    uniqueAut = Author.query.filter_by(name=au.strip()).first()
                    if not uniqueAut:
                        uniqueAut = Author(name = au.strip())
                    authorlist.append(uniqueAut)
            aut = Author(name = authorlist)

            db.session.add(aut)
            db.session.commit()
```

Comment: What does your form class look like?

Comment: How are you submitting your form? By using a submit button on it? Using javascript? Have you tried to investigate if the values are at least hitting the backend but not being saved or if they are not sent at all by the frontend?

Comment: @dim Post has been edited with class. @maccinza I use a submit button. I tested with jquery serialize to convert the values into JSON and I found that the values get returned as `author[]:['value1', 'value2',..., 'valueN']`. My db never sees this though. It only gets an empty string.

Comment: don't you need to change `value="{ value1here }"` to `value="{{value1here }}"`?

Comment: @mankadanka That's just a way to show what is in the value. Has nothing to do with flask.